# Android : set selected item of a Spinner from DB with Cursor

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor, spinner

I have a problem with Cursors.
I have 3 tables in my DB : facture (means invoice), vehicule (vehicle) and garage.

An invoice concerns one vehicle and one garage. When I create an invoice, I select the vehicle and the garage from spinners.

When I want to update an invoice, I need to set the item selected in these spinners.

Here is how I do :

```
    for (int iVhc = 0; iVhc < spListeVhc.getCount(); iVhc++) {
        Cursor valueVhc = (Cursor) spListeVhc.getItemAtPosition(iVhc);
        long idVhc = facture.getLong(facture.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TB_VEHICULE._id"));
        long idSpVhc = valueVhc.getLong(valueVhc.getColumnIndex("TB_VEHICULE._id"));

        if (idSpVhc == idVhc) {
            spListeVhc.setSelection(iVhc);
        }
    }


    for (int iGar = 0; iGar < spListeGar.getCount(); iGar++) {
        Cursor valueGar = (Cursor) spListeGar.getItemAtPosition(iGar);
        long idGar = facture.getLong(facture.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TB_GARAGE._id"));
        long idSpGar = valueGar.getLong(valueGar.getColumnIndex("TB_GARAGE._id"));

        if (idSpGar == idGar) {
            spListeGar.setSelection(iGar);
        }
    }
```

It works for the garage, but the problem is that, for a reason that I don't understand, the spinner of vehicles takes the same ID than the garage.

That means, if the garage selected has the ID 2 in the DB, the selected vehicle will be the vehicle with ID 2 too.

??

Here is my query to get the invoice:

```
public Cursor recupFacture(long idFacture){
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT TB_FACTURE._id, libelle_fa,  date_fa, nom_vhc, kilometrage_fa, nom_garage, remarque_fa, date_paie_fa,  montant_fa, TB_VEHICULE._id, TB_GARAGE._id" +
                        " FROM TB_FACTURE, TB_VEHICULE, TB_GARAGE" +
                        " WHERE fk_vhc_fa = TB_VEHICULE._id" +
                        " AND fk_gar_fa = TB_GARAGE._id" +
                        " AND TB_FACTURE._id ="+idFacture, null);
}
```

And I realised that I have thi kind of mistakes in my log :

```
08-10 12:54:22.431: ERROR/Cursor(17072): requesting column name with table name -- TB_VEHICULE._id
```

And same for garage...

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT :**

I found a solution.

I replaced the TB_GARAGE._id and TB_VEHICULE._id by the fk at the lines :

```
long idVhc = facture.getLong(facture.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TB_VEHICULE._id"));
long idGar = facture.getLong(facture.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TB_GARAGE._id"));
```

However, I can't really explain why it works like this but not with the ID.
The prefix of the table causes a strange mistake...

Comment: This error comes from the fact that I write TB.GARAGE/VEHICULE._id
If I write just _id, I have the same problem but no more mistake in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the invoice correctly? Make sure you are not accidentally saving the garage ID as vehicle ID as well.

Otherwise, how is "fracture" defined? Perhaps there is a mistake there.

Comment: Yes because I display them in a ListView and both garage and vehicle are correct.
I add some other code and an error that I receive (didn't see it before :-X)